# Swiper is ignoring ng-content

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm trying to migrate from `ngx-swiper-wrapper` to `swiper` in Angular 10. My approach is to have as modular solution as possible. Because of that I want to have a swiper-wrapper.component and swiper-slide.component.

Thanks to that I can pass different components into swiper and in case I need to modify how swiper-slide behave in the future I only need to do this in 1 place.

This approach worked pretty well in `ngx-swiper-wrapper` however `swiper` is ignoring `ng-content` and I can render anything :-(

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-virtual-tkmhct?file=src/app/s-carousel/s-carousel.component.html) to my current solution.

*Root.component.html*

```
 <app-swiper-carousel [options]="virtualConfig">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of allSlides">
      <app-swiper-slide>
        <!-- I can render any component here -->
        <div>
          {{ slide.firstName + '&nbsp;' + slide.lastName }}
        </div>
      </app-swiper-slide>
    </ng-container>
  </app-swiper-carousel>
```

*swiper-carousel.ts*

```
<swiper #swip [config]="virtualConfig" [virtual]="true">
  <!-- This doesnt' work :-(  -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>

  <!-- Uncomment this to make it work -->
  <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of virtualSlides.slides">
    <ng-template swiperSlide>
      <div>
        {{ slide.firstName + '&nbsp;' + slide.lastName }}
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container> -->
</swiper>
```

*swiper-slide.component

```
<ng-template swiperSlide>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Any idea if I'm doing something wrong or there is a bug in swiper?
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Hey @DejaVu, I raised this question on swiper github discussion [link](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/discussions/4587).@vitansky answered that it's achievable and shared this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-virtual-gfwsjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fs-carousel%2Fs-carousel.component.ts) but I didn't have chance to look into it (it's on my TODO list) :-(

Comment: @Kosmonaft I tried the solution suggested in the link but it didn't work for my case where I need the slides to loop :(     
Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Create this two directive,

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSwiperTemplate]',
})
export class SwiperTemplateDirective {}

@Directive({
  selector: 'appSwiperContent',
})
export class SwiperContentDirective {
  @ContentChild(SwiperTemplateDirective, { read: TemplateRef })
  template!: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;
}
```

Change ng-content with this.

```
 <swiper [config]="config">
      <ng-template *ngFor="let slide of contents" swiperSlide>
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="slide.template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
              $implicit: slide.template
            }"></ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </swiper>
```

add this line in .ts file

```
  @ContentChildren(SwiperContentDirective, {
    descendants: true,
  })
  contents!: QueryList<SwiperContentDirective>;
```

and use it like this.

```
<app-swiper-form>
  <appSwiperContent *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <ng-template appSwiperTemplate>
      .
      . Your code
      .
    </ng-template>
  </appSwiperContent>
</app-swiper-form>
```

Comment: I had a hard time to understand this snippet (because of the lack of explanations) but, indeed, it works.

Additional notes: 
(1) I add `// eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/directive-selector` over the `appSwiperContent` and use it as `app-swiper-content` instead
(2) It's a drawback to need two nested nodes (`appSwiperContent` and `ng-template`) to display the slide content (compared to the built-in solution of swiper.js) but I'd still go this way for encapsulation purposes.